# how to optimize 'for' loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

i want optimize some loop code such as below . my code is working with large matrix and must be optimized . please help me .

**Example one:** Expecting **Boolean** results:

```
m=zeros(100,100);
r=rand(100,100);
for i=1:100
    for j=1:100
        if(r(i,j)<0.3 || r(i,j)>0.7)
            m(i,j)=1;
        else
            m(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

**Example two:** Expecting **NON-Boolean** results

```
m=zeros(100,100);
r=rand(100,100);
for i=1:100
    for j=1:100
        if(r(i,j)<0.3 || r(i,j)>0.7)
            m(i,j)=0.035;
        else
            m(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Vectorize:

```
m = r<0.3 | r>0.7;
```

This gives a `boolean` result. You may want to convert `m` to `double`: `m = double(m);`.

Comment: its good but if we wont boolean  answer,what we must do? for example if m(i,j)=.035 insted of m(i,j)=1?

Comment: @RezaGhanami `m * 0.035`?

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: [Luis Mendo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) answer

```
r=rand(100,100);
m = r<0.3 | r>0.7;
```

Example 2:

```
m(100,100) = 0;
r=rand(100,100);
m(r<0.3 | r>0.7) = 0.035;
```